# Can geography datatype Lat/Long properties be returned using a view in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, c#, spatial

Hopefully the question is fairly self-explanatory.

I've been ferreting through the, what appears to be quite minimal/poor microsoft documentation regarding both views and geography datatypes in the sql server 2008, and I *think* the answer is "no, geography datatypes are either not supported or minimally supported within a view"; but I'm not entirely sure, and I'd love some corroboration.

I've been attempting to add geography data to an existing view. And my end goal is to retrieve longitude/latitude data from the field in question.

Here's the select statement (simplified) that works when applied to the table but doesn't work when defined within the view:

```
SELECT     
    [dbo.vendor.location].Lat AS latitude,
FROM         
    dbo.vendor
```

Note that `[dbo.vendor.location]` is the field, and `Lat` is the latitude property of the `geography` datatype.

And when that sql is run within the view, the following error is returned:

```
The multi-part identifier "dbo.vendor.location.Lat" could not be bound
```

---

Edit:

Note that I've also tried the following query, with similar results:

```
SELECT     
    [dbo].[vendor].[location].Lat AS latitude,
FROM         
    dbo.vendor
```

In this case, SQL Management Studio removes the quotes and returns the same "multi-part ... could not be bound" error.

Comment: Drop the quotes on your column name. The way it's written, you're telling SQL Server to look for a single object/column named "dbo.vendor.location", and not a multi-part name (schema.table.column). Quote them individually if you must. (`[dbo].[vendor].[location]`)

Comment: Oh, yes, I might have mentioned that I tried that, with similar results. I'll add it in an edit.

Comment: There is no way that that SQL query works "when applied to the table".  And Views in SQL Server support just about anything that you can do with a valid data-`SELECT` statement, excepting the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reference it as `[dbo].[vendor].[location].Lat` in the `SELECT` list.

use simply `vendor.location.Lat` or `location.Lat` or define a table alias and use that.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vendor([location] geography)

GO

/*Works fine*/
CREATE VIEW V1
AS
SELECT     
   v.location.Lat AS latitude
FROM         
    dbo.vendor v

GO

/*Fails*/
CREATE VIEW V2
AS
SELECT     
   dbo.vendor.location.Lat AS latitude
FROM         
    dbo.vendor
```

The use of the column `dbo.vendor.location` on its own (without the CLR property call) does in fact still work in the column list but the use of "More than two-part column name" is on the [list of deprecated TSQL features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) anyway.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Yep, the existing view used the `dbo...` notation in all the column selections, so being the SS2008 newb that I am, I assumed it would work for this case as well. Glad the answer was so simple!

Comment: I just wanted to add that in order for this to work you must delete ALL instances of the 'dbo' notation in your query.